# Isn't that async misleading when it actually means run synchronously?

Tags: javascript, async-await

I mean the following code is just run synchronously:

```
 someReceiveACallback('event', async () {
   const result = await imAsync() /*1*/
   let anotherResult = null /*2*/
   if (result.authenticated)
     anotherResult = await imAlsoAsync() /*3*/
   send(anotherResult) /*4*/
 })
```

The flow is just: 1->2->3->4, as if it's synchronous.

If the default behaviour is asynchrous, why mark it as `async` when it indeed makes thing synchronous?

Comment: `async` doesn't mean it's synchronous.  But `await` *does* mean that you want to wait for the result of the operation.  The semantics are more clear if you include all of the terms being used, not just one.

Comment: @David: Why mark the anonymous function `async` to use `await`, which part become async?

Comment: Async is just sugar coating for promises. It is async, but written in an synchronous way. Picture every await as a callback/promise instead.

Comment: @s̮̦̩e̝͓c̮͔̞ṛ̖̖e̬̣̦t̸͉̥̳̼: The function is marked as `async` because it's an asynchronous operation.  You can choose to `await` the operation or not.  When you invoke an asynchronous operation, it is executed asynchronously.  When you await that operation, you wait for its result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### No, it does not mean run synchronously

[`async`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) and [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) are "syntactic sugar" for [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). What that means is that the syntax is equivalent to the following in ES2015 and ES2016, running a [generator function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*) as a [coroutine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coroutine).

```
someReceiveACallback('event', coroutine(function*() {
  const result = yield imAsync(); /*1*/
  let anotherResult = null; /*2*/
  if (result.authenticated)
    anotherResult = yield imAlsoAsync(); /*3*/
  send(anotherResult); /*4*/
}));

function coroutine(fn) {
  return function() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const gen = fn.apply(this, arguments);
      const step = method => result => {
        try {
          var { value, done } = gen[method](result);
        } catch (error) {
          reject(error);
          return;
        }

        if (done) resolve(value);
        else Promise.resolve(value).then(_next, _throw);
      };

      const _next = step('next');
      const _throw = step('throw');

      _next(undefined);
    });
  };
}
```

<sup>[Original code generated by babel](https://babeljs.io/repl#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=IYZwngdgxgBAZgV2gFwJYHsI2QUxMmACgEoYBvAKBhik3xgCc8EAbAgXhmAHdhUDUAWwCC4aCRgB6AFQBGaZKowWOAsAjpkACxwMASszYxOEViynSATAqWo4RJiFbIAdMATacENFGC4AJsRK1OqaOvqGHFy8_DBCwiwg6KKQUBIyAMw21CBe_oShnhFObKQyACw2AL4UQA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=false&presets=es2017&prettier=false&targets=&version=7.5.5&externalPlugins=)</sup>

In simple terms, only everything up until the first encountered `await` expression is run synchronously. This is due to the `_next(undefined)` call in the executor of the `Promise` constructor.

After that, the function returns a promise to the caller that settles when the function's execution has reached the end of its control flow.

Each block between consecutively encountered `await` expressions runs within its own asynchronous continuation `.then(...)`.

The purpose of the coroutine is to run the [promise resolution procedure](https://promisesaplus.com/#the-promise-resolution-procedure) on each [`yield`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/yield) expression encountered in the generator. When the promise settles, the coroutine asynchronously re-enters the control flow at the same point, providing the resolved value or throwing the rejected reason. The `Promise.resolve(value).then(_next, _throw)` is what does this.

With native support for `async` / `await`, everything done by `coroutine()` is actually implemented in the runtime's event loop.

Comment: Thanks for your kindness.

Answer (score -1):

This code doesn't run synchronous. It just runs in order and looks synchronous. 
If your function is using async methods, you can mark it with 'async' type.

And 'await', marks the asynchronous part

Comment: So the function marked `async` will be scheduled to run after main thread finish its synchronous jobs? That is could you answer my last comment below my question? (i didn't downvote your answer)